# Hide items with javascript in tipue search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I'm trying to modify tipueSearch.

Tipue search looks in the `_content.js` for matching results and every result is built like:

```
var tipuesearch = {
    "pages": [
    {
        "title": "",
        "text": "",
        "tags": "",
        "loc": "",
    },
    ...
```

I want to add another item called category.

```
"category": "example_a",
```

I want to create a button which removes all items with category, example_a from the results.

I tried to accomplish this by adding a div class instead of a category, and hide onclick. However tipuesearch acts like the results are still there.

When 2 items displayed as a result and both items are `category example_a` both items will be hidden. Resulting an empty page, and `result 3, 4, 5` etc sitting on the next few pages.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Yes, removing DOM elements isn't the same as removing items from a JavaScript object. You'll need to do both.

Comment: i know that, but i don't know how to hide items from a javascript object